# Count all values in a matrix less than a value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pixel

I have to count all the values in a matrix (2-d array) that are less than 200.

The code I wrote down for this is:

```
za=0   
p31 = numpy.asarray(o31)   
for i in range(o31.size[0]):   
    for j in range(o32.size[1]):   
        if p31[i,j]<200:   
            za=za+1   
print za
```

`o31` is an image and I am converting it into a matrix and then finding the values.

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Doesn't this just print the number of values that are less than 200, and not the actual values?

Comment: Yes.. I just need the total of all the values instead of the actual values themselves.

Comment: You aren't getting the total here either. Set `za` to an empty list `za = []`, then `za.append(p31[i,j])`, finally out of your for loop, `print sum(za)`; but I'm sure there is a better way since you are using numpy.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

The `numpy.where` function is your friend. Because it's implemented to take full advantage of the array datatype, for large images you should notice a speed improvement over the pure python solution you provide.

Using numpy.where directly will yield a boolean mask indicating whether certain values match your conditions:

```
>>> data
array([[1, 8],
       [3, 4]])
>>> numpy.where( data > 3 )
(array([0, 1]), array([1, 1]))
```

And the mask can be used to index the array directly to get the actual values:

```
>>> data[ numpy.where( data > 3 ) ]
array([8, 4])
```

Exactly where you take it from there will depend on what form you'd like the results in.

Comment: Thanks... But I need the total number of values, not the values themselves.. should I do sum(numpy.where(data<200))?

Comment: If you want the number OF values, not the sum, you would do len(numpy.where(data<200))

Comment: if condition changed to > 0, then it will return (array([0, 0, 1, 1]), array([0, 1, 0, 1])), what does it mean? or is it a bug?

Comment: This method is unnecessarily complex. @neonneo's method is much more straightforward and does a better job of answering the question.

Comment: @jimh for me np.where returns a tuple, gotta do len(np.where(...)[0])

Answer (score 131):

This is very straightforward with boolean arrays:

```
p31 = numpy.asarray(o31)
za = (p31 < 200).sum() # p31<200 is a boolean array, so `sum` counts the number of True elements
```

Comment: I think this should be the top answer. The `np.where` also works obviously, but gives additional information which is not required here and makes the answer a bit less straightforward, and performance a bit slower

Answer (score 32):

There are many ways to achieve this, like flatten-and-filter or simply enumerate, but I think using [Boolean/mask array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) is the easiest one (and iirc a much faster one):

```
>>> y = np.array([[123,24123,32432], [234,24,23]])
array([[  123, 24123, 32432],
       [  234,    24,    23]])
>>> b = y > 200
>>> b
array([[False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False, False]], dtype=bool)
>>> y[b]
array([24123, 32432,   234])
>>> len(y[b])
3
>>>> y[b].sum()
56789
```

**Update**:

As nneonneo has answered, if all you want is the number of elements that passes threshold, you can simply do:

```
>>>> (y>200).sum()
3
```

which is a simpler solution.

---

Speed comparison with `filter`:

```
### use boolean/mask array ###

b = y > 200

%timeit y[b]
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.31 us per loop

%timeit y[y>200]
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.57 us per loop

### use filter ###

x = y.ravel()
%timeit filter(lambda x:x>200, x)
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.33 us per loop

%timeit np.array(filter(lambda x:x>200, x))
10000 loops, best of 3: 21.7 us per loop

%timeit filter(lambda x:x>200, y.ravel())
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.2 us per loop

%timeit np.array(filter(lambda x:x>200, y.ravel()))
10000 loops, best of 3: 22.9 us per loop

*** use numpy.where ***

nb = np.where(y>200)
%timeit y[nb]
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.42 us per loop

%timeit y[np.where(y>200)]
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.3 us per loop
```

Comment: `timeit y[b]` omits half the code from the computation done in filter. `%timeit y[y>200]` is equivalent-ish.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a variant that uses fancy indexing and has the actual values as an intermediate:

```
p31 = numpy.asarray(o31)
values = p31[p31<200]
za = len(values)
```

Comment: This is just regular boolean indexing.

Answer (score 6):

To count the number of values larger than x in any numpy array you can use:

```
n = len(matrix[matrix > x])
```

The boolean indexing returns an array that contains only the elements where the condition (matrix > x) is met. Then len() counts these values.

Comment: You probably need to explain why this works. Overloaded `__gt__` I guess, but that's not obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [numpy.count_nonzero](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html), converting the whole into a one-liner:

```py
za = numpy.count_nonzero(numpy.asarray(o31)<200)  #as written in the code
```

Comment: You could avoid an explicit call to `asarray` with `np.count_nonzero(np.less_than(o3, 200))`.