# Fastest way to count array values above a threshold in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, boolean

I have a numpy array containing 10^8 floats and want to count how many of them are >= a given threshold.  Speed is crucial because the operation has to be done on large numbers of such arrays. The contestants so far are

```
np.sum(myarray >= thresh)

np.size(np.where(np.reshape(myarray,-1) >= thresh))
```

The answers at [Count all values in a matrix greater than a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995937/count-all-values-in-a-matrix-greater-than-a-value) suggest that np.where() would be faster, but I've found inconsistent timing results.  What I mean by this is for **some** realizations and Boolean conditions np.size(np.where(cond)) is faster than np.sum(cond), but for some it is slower.

Specifically, if a large fraction of entries fulfil the condition then np.sum(cond) is significantly faster but if a small fraction (maybe less than a tenth) do then np.size(np.where(cond)) wins.

The question breaks down into 2 parts:

- Any other suggestions?
- Does it make sense that the time taken by np.size(np.where(cond)) increases with the number of entries for which cond is true?

Comment: numexpr or numba could probably speed things up by avoiding the creation of an intermediate array.

Comment: there is also np.count_nonzero which is much faster than boolean sum on new numpy versions.

Answer (score 3):

Using cython might be a decent alternative.

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
from cython.parallel import prange


DTYPE_f64 = np.float64
ctypedef np.float64_t DTYPE_f64_t


@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
cdef int count_above_cython(DTYPE_f64_t [:] arr_view, DTYPE_f64_t thresh) nogil:

    cdef int length, i, total
    total = 0
    length = arr_view.shape[0]

    for i in prange(length):
        if arr_view[i] >= thresh:
            total += 1

    return total


@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
def count_above(np.ndarray arr, DTYPE_f64_t thresh):

    cdef DTYPE_f64_t [:] arr_view = arr.ravel()
    cdef int total

    with nogil:
       total =  count_above_cython(arr_view, thresh)
    return total
```

Timing of different proposed methods.

```
myarr = np.random.random((1000,1000))
thresh = 0.33

In [6]: %timeit count_above(myarr, thresh)
1000 loops, best of 3: 693 µs per loop

In [9]: %timeit np.count_nonzero(myarr >= thresh)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.45 ms per loop

In [11]: %timeit np.sum(myarr >= thresh)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.86 ms per loop

In [12]: %timeit np.size(np.where(np.reshape(myarr,-1) >= thresh))
10 loops, best of 3: 61.6 ms per loop
```

With a larger array:

```
In [13]: myarr = np.random.random(10**8)

In [14]: %timeit count_above(myarr, thresh)
10 loops, best of 3: 63.4 ms per loop

In [15]: %timeit np.count_nonzero(myarr >= thresh)
1 loops, best of 3: 473 ms per loop

In [16]: %timeit np.sum(myarr >= thresh)
1 loops, best of 3: 511 ms per loop

In [17]: %timeit np.size(np.where(np.reshape(myarr,-1) >= thresh))
1 loops, best of 3: 6.07 s per loop
```

Comment: I guess it will depend on hardware, and in cython you can easier parallelize. With -O3 in cython (without its slow) and development numpy, on my computer they perform close to identical (slight edge for cython but the numpy code is much faster with uncontiguous arrays, though you can fix that of course). However you should really use `ssize_t`/`np.intp_t` and *not* int, that is a bug otherwise.